# RSelenium Extract text from site

Tags: r, rselenium

I need to copy and paste the text from a website. I'm currently using the code below to open a browser session, and select the text form the page. However I have not been able to figure out how to copy the text after I selected it.

```
library(RSelenium)

rD <- rsDriver(browser = "chrome"
           ,verbose = TRUE
           ,chromever = "73.0.3683.68")

 Sys.sleep(3)

remDr <- rD[["client"]]

remDr$navigate("https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RSelenium/vignettes/basics.html")

remDr$sendKeysToActiveElement(list(key = 'control',"a", key = 'control')) # select text
```

I need to find out how to copy and read text from the clipboard.

Comment: Why copy the text? You can use `youElement$getElementText()` to extract texts from a selected element. If you really need to do literal `copy`, use `write.table("your selected text","clipboard",row.names = FALSE,col.names = FALSE)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code copies the text from the page

```
library(RSelenium)

rD <- rsDriver(browser = "chrome"
       ,verbose = TRUE
       ,chromever = "73.0.3683.68")

 Sys.sleep(3)

remDr <- rD[["client"]]

remDr$navigate("https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RSelenium/vignettes/basics.html")

remDr$sendKeysToActiveElement(list(key = 'control',"a", key = 'control')) # select text

remDr$sendKeysToActiveElement(list(key = 'control',"c", key = 'control')) # copy text to memory

df <- read.table(file = "clipboard", # save to df from clipboard
         header = F,
        skip = 2,
        fill = TRUE,
         sep = "\t")
dim(df)
[1] 260   1
```